# iOS - How do I add search bar function to this array?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

can someone please tell me how to add the search function to an array that contains the titles of rss news links that i have gathered using the xml parser in Xcode 4.6.2 here in the following code? All i basically want is to be able to go to the search bar in my viewcontroller whilst in the simulator or app, and be able to search through the different rss headlines which fill the tableview cell in the ns url array i have here in the code.

```
     // 

    #import "SocialMasterViewController.h"

    #import "SocialDetailViewController.h"

    @interface SocialMasterViewController () {
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSString *element;
NSMutableArray *totalStrings;
NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
BOOL isFiltered;
    }

    @end

    @implementation SocialMasterViewController



    -(void)gotosharing {
UIStoryboard *sharingStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Sharing" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialSharingVC = [sharingStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
initialSharingVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentViewController:initialSharingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }


    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
[super awakeFromNib];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self;


feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rssmix.com/u/3747019/rss.xml"
        ];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];


    }



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table View

    // table view and my data source's and delegate methods......

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView         {
return 1;
    }



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
return cell;

static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";


    }


    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"])         {

    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName         {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])         {

    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string         {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"])         {
    [title appendString:string];
        } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"])         {
    [link appendString:string];
        }

    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser         {

[self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender         {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])         {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

        }
    }


    @end
```

btw this is my masterviewcontroller.m file code

Looking forward to ur response guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime your search bar changes you want to update the contents of the table view.
So, first you filter the url strings then update tableView by reloading the data.

1) Make the calls when search bar changes:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self filterURLsWithSearchBar:searchText];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

2) filter the strings you want to show

```
- (void)filterURLsWithSearchBar:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [filteredStrings removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *rssUrl in totalStrings)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [rssUrl compare:searchText 
                                         options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) 
                                           range:[rssUrl rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)]];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            [self.filteredStrings addObject:rssUrl];
        }
    }
}
```

3) reload table data (needs to change the # of rows and the datasource)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.mySerchBar.text isEqualToString:@""] || self.mySearchBar.text == NULL) {
        return totalStrings.count;
    }
    else {
        return filteredStrings.count;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    if ([self.mySearchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]|| self.mySearchBar.text == NULL)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [totalStrings objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the filterURLsWithSearchBar:searchText is function that you define, so you need to also add -(void)filterURLsWithSearchBar:(NSString *)searchText; to your .h file